# MongoDB performance with $in

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm developing a web service that is being load tested. So that I don't waste anyone's time, I won't go into detail about the REST API because it's too complicated to explain.

I'm developing with Node and using MongoDB's native Node driver. I use the following query:

```
let mediaIdQuery = {_id: {$in: media}};
let result = await db.collection(COLLECTION_MEDIA).findOne(mediaIdQuery);
```

'media' is an array of strings. I'm essentially searching the database to see if I have a document with an _id that is in the array.

I add these documents elsewhere. In testing, it seems to work fine when the creation of the documents and search query for them are far apart in time. However, if I send a request that creates a document and a search request within ~100 ms of each other it seems that this query fails to find the document.

This is actually an attempt at optimization on my part. In the past, I had a for loop that went through each individual array element and sent a separate search query each time. This, should be able to do it all in 1 query, so I figure it should be faster. When I used the for loop method, everything worked properly.

I'm just really confused why the database can't find the documents when the requests are close in time. I'm 100% sure that the insert queries of the documents occur before the search request occurs because it takes pretty much 0ms to insert the documents, and the insert queries are sent first. Is there some sort of delay in MongoDB's system before the documents are visible? I've never experienced issues with anything like that before, so I'm hesitant to blame it on a delay in the system. Any ideas?

Edit:
My database is not sharded. Everything is stored on 1 instance.

Comment: Are the queries going to a secondary and possibly not finding the newly created doc due to a delay with replication?

Comment: No. I only have 1 instance holding the database. I did not shard.